# How do you find the amount for two different types of payments are indifferent?

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

The annual effective interest rate is 10% compounded monthly.

Deal A: You give me $4000 today and I pay you back 2000 dollars in 1 year, and 4000 dollars in 2 years.

Deal B: I give you 2000 dollars today and another 4000 dollars in 1 year and you pay me $X in 2 years.

What does $X have to be for you to be indifferent between these two deals?
How can I set up the present values for both?

Comment: Hint: Set the two present values of the two deals equal and solve for $X$.

Comment: What are the present values of the 2 deals?

Comment: For deal A: PV = 2000/(1/(1+0.1/12)^12) + 4000(1/(1+0.1/12)^12)) 

For deal B I'm stuck.

Im not sure if I stetted up the PV for deal A correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. At deal $A$ you´ve forgotten the payment from "you" of $\$4000$ at the beginning. This amount has not to be discounted.

$$\texttt{PV of Deal A}: \quad-4000+\frac{2000}{\left(1+\frac{0.1}{12}\right)^{12}}+\frac{4000}{\left(1+\frac{0.1}{12}\right)^{24}}$$

For Deal B you start with a positive sign, since "you" get $\$2000$.

$$\texttt{PV of Deal B}: \quad 2000+\frac{4000}{\left(1+\frac{0.1}{12}\right)^{12}}+\frac{X}{\left(1+\frac{0.1}{12}\right)^{24}}$$